# React is not able to render JPG image on the page while it's working fine with the PNG

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add an image to my react website locally. So, I did `<img src={require('./wally.jpg')} />` but it didn't seem to work. Then I tried the same thing with PNG `<img src={require('./wally.png')} />` and it worked. So, the problem is I am not able to add JPG image on the react website. Why JPG is not rendering ?

I have tried:

> 1. Importing image before rendering.
> 2. Using `<img src={require('image url')} />`
> 3. installing url-loader and file-loader.
> 4. using css to upload the image.
> 5. using `<img src='./wally.jpg' />`
> 6. Also tried changing the image's location.

HomePage.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./HomePage.css";


class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "HomePage">
        <h1 className = "HomeHeading">Navin Kumar</h1>
        <img src={require('./wally.jpg')} />
        <p className = "HomeContent">Few Good lines about me.</p>
      </div>
   )
 }
}
export default HomePage;
```

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/portfolio/src');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/portfolio/dist');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: `${SRC_DIR}/index.jsx`,
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css']
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&minetype=image/png'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : SRC_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',      
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
       }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
};
```

I expected the output to show the image but it is showing the image holder(same icon that shows up when image is not found by a html file) and when i try it to open it in the new tab it opens a blank page. So, there is no problem in build but at console it shows undefined.

Comment: You're setting mime type image/png, that won't work with jpeg. Try configuring two different URL loaders, one for png and one for jpg, each with appropriate mime type

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved the day. That was it. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You’re attempting to pass the jpg through the png loader here `test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,`. If you remove the reference to jpg here it will fall through the next loader and should work fine.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for replying  and I tried what you said but it still doesn't work. It shows image placeholder icon instead of the image.In fact I added that `jpg`  while trying out different things. I also think there is something wrong with the `webpack.config.js` but I don't know what.